# Table design for efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a requirement to develop a system. Part of the system is that, every day, a payment for a person is calculated (A person gets given $x.xx per day, based on some rules), and stored in a Transaction table, which at the moment, consists of the personId, the amount and the date.

```
CREATE TABLE DailyTransaction
(
   DailyTransaction INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   PersonId INT NOT NULL,
   TransactionDate DATE NOT NULL
)
```

There are 8,000 people in the system right now, so every day, 8,000 rows are written via a process to the table.

I think, storing the date, is repeating too much. And there may be queries on that date later. So, I'd like to create a 'DailyRun' table, which contains a date, and and id (and more columns later, if needed). So, when I do a daily payment insert run to populate the 8,000 rows, I first create a DailyRun record with the date, and then assign that ID for that row, to the Transaction table.

```
CREATE TABLE DailyRun
(
    DailyRunId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    RunDate DATE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE DailyTransaction
(
   DailyTransaction INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   PersonId INT NOT NULL,
   DailyRunId INT NOT NULL
)
```

So, if I wanted all the rows for a specific date, I find the date in the DailyRun table, and then get all the record associated to it, via a foreign key, to the Transaction Table.

That seems OK so far (Unless someone sees an issue?)

BUT, now the issue.

Another requirement is that during the day, an ad-hoc payment can be added to the transaction table. So, an extra one-off payment. But, it doesn't get created as a Run. So, no row in the DailyRun table. An idea is a nullable DailyRun ID in the Transaction table, but ... when I need to get all the transactions for a specific date - well, there's no date field... and now RunID set.. so it won't be found.

What I can do is allow for Null RunID, and also have a nullable 'AdHocPaymentDate' field. So, if it's an Adhoc payment, I can leave RunID null, and populate AdHocPaymentDate?

And if it's a Scheduled payment run, I populate the RunID, and leave the AdHocPaymentDate as null?

But, aren't nullable fields slow, or not recommended for some reason?

Is there a better way to handle this? Maybe a separate 'Ad Hock Payment' table, which holds the ad hoc payments, in addition to the table that holds the regular daily payments?

Comment: "I think, storing the date, is repeating too much" - that's probably a bad guess. A `date` requires 3 bytes to store it (`datetime` requires 8, `datetime2` between 6 and 8 bytes) - compared to the overheads of creating a new table, indexing it efficiently and putting the FK in place? And as with any performance question, the only way to really know is to try things out with *your* data in *your* environment. Remote performance tuning via hunches and feelings rarely works.

Comment: Thanks Damien. The extra table could also hold extra data which I would find useful, such as a processed status flag (Has that run been processed and sent form payment?). But I agree - if it just has the date - it's maybe not useful.

Comment: Even if you need to store a lot of additional information into DailyRun table later, then for queries efficiency I would duplicate TransactionDate into DailyTransaction table (using your first design). We have some table pairs (document-rows) in our legacy data structures, it is global PITA to query rows and link header only to get date from there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a business requirement to distinguish the ad hoc payments from the daily runs. I guess you could work with this kind of solution. Using 'DailyRun' and 'AdHoc' as transaction types and then making the business intelligence insert the transaction properly from daily runs (service) and adhocs (user interaction)

```
CREATE TABLE [TransactionType]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(40)
)

CREATE TABLE [Transaction]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [TransactionTypeId] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TransationType
    [PersonId] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES person
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to approach your concern about repeating values in rows. The best I can offer is that there's no principle of normalization that says, "Hunt for values that appear in more than one row. If you find them, replace then with integers and another table." Anyway, if you do that, you'll have row after row of repeating integers.

Also, since both "run" and ad hoc payments have a date, there's no logical reason to remove the date from the table of transactions.

---

**How I'd start . . .**

By your description, this isn't a table of transactions. It's a table of payments.

```
create table payments (
  payment_id integer not null,
  payment_date date not null,
  payment_amount decimal(12, 2) not null
    check (payment_amount > 0),
  -- For identifying a(d hoc) and r(un) payments
  payment_type char(1) not null
    check (payment_type in ('a', 'r')),
  person_id integer not null,  -- references a table not shown
  primary key (payment_id), 
  unique (payment_id, payment_type),
  unique (payment_date, payment_type, person_id)
);
```

The unique constraint on {payment_date, payment_type, person_id} is important. Your description seems to require no more than one "run" payment per date per person, and no more than one ad hoc payment per date per person. In any case, you need a unique constraint on the real data in addition to a primary key constraint on the surrogate ID number.

The unique constraint on {payment_id, payment_type} is also important. If you need to store more details about either run payments or about ad hoc payments, you can build a table like this.

```
create table payments_ad_hoc (
  payment_id integer not null,
  payment_type char(1) not null 
    default 'a'
    check (payment_type = 'a'),
  other_columns_go_here char(1) not null 
    default 'x',
  primary key (payment_id),
  foreign key (payment_id, payment_type)
    references payments (payment_id, payment_type)
);
```

The combination of the check constraint and the foreign key constraint guarantees that rows in this table will reference an ad hoc payment, not just *any* payment. Structure for "run" payments would be similar.